# How does word2vec parse a text file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, word2vec

When I use word2vec.word2vec(train="corpus.txt"), how does it parse words out of the file?

Could somebody give me an example or related resources? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which `word2vec` software are you using? The practices will vary by different libraries/packages.

Comment: Are you talking about gensim?

Comment: @gojomo @ToussaintLouverture Sorry for late response. I simply `pip install word2vec` and `import word2vec`

Comment: Ah. I'm not familiar with the operation of that package (which seems to wrap the original Google word2vec.c code).

Answer (score 0):

There are more different resources how to do it. One of the [possible way](https://streamhacker.com/2014/12/29/word2vec-nltk/) to use word2vec technique with gensim is [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) or on [git](https://github.com/lesley2958/word2vec).

The main idea to use word2vec is the opportunity to handle words like vectors. It is very comfortable from calculation process.

Assuming you have a text where there are many words. If you will create dictionary only using those words you will have misunderstanding later because their meaning into multi dimension space will be wrong. If you will be use vectors from base on given word2vec models from Google, etc. you will have better distribution of words into defined space.

Having model, you can easy calculate similarity and so on to extract meaning from the text. It's already a logical part and will be related with you intention.